# Can I get the address bar url from the javascript console when the page has failed to load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Just say I typed in a bad hostname in the address bar.

For example, say I wasn't running a local web server, and I load:

`http://localhost/callback_url`

In Chrome, this will give me a "This webpage is not available" message.

**Is there anyway I can find out what the url is in the address bar from the Javascript console, even though the page failed to load?**

I know I can normally use `window.location.href` to get this, but that returns `"data:text/html,chromewebdata"` in this instance.

So in this example, I'd like to know if there's some javascript that returns `http://localohost/callback_url`

**EDIT:** The main reason I'd like to do this is so I know if server side redirect failed when using ChromeDriver with Selenium. So I'd prefer to avoid using extensions if possible, and am open to Chrome and ChromeDriver specific solutions if applicable! The callback_url may have extra info in it, added by the server, and I'd like to see what this info is. I'd like to avoid running another server to get this data if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loadTimeData` object included in the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` page has the failed URL:

```
> loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl
"http://localhost/foo?request_url=bar"
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! I was using the above approach before, but now that's stopped working and gives back a data url. This seems to work fine for our usage with [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1313)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the title of the page.
By typing `document.title` and doing some regex you can get the URL.

Another way I found is by using the following

```
var data = loadTimeData.createJsEvalContext();
console.log(data.a.$top.summary.failedUrl);
```

If you open the developer tools and search for a part of the URL in source code, you will see that Chrome creates the `loadTimeData` in the "not available page".

Comment: I ended up using `document.title`, as this was available both from javascript, and from Chrome Webdriver as well. In Ruby it was `@browser.title`

Comment: To follow on @BradParks in `capybara`, all that was required for me was to use `page.driver.browser.title`